# reading from XML file to Sql server table C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I want to read data from XML file to sql server table, my code works properly if all nod is exist but if one of the node isn't exist it show me errors
here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <DocumentElement>
 <student>
 <rfidip>3000E2009150501900880530DE07</rfidip>
 <timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
 <timegetout>2013-04-09T00:55:59+03:00</timegetout>
 </student>
<student>
<rfidip>3000E20075232318015114907CF6</rfidip>
<timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
<timegetout>2013-04-09T00:55:59+03:00</timegetout>
</student>
<student>
 <rfidip>3000E20075232318015112409741</rfidip>
 <timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
 </student>
 </DocumentElement>
```

and this is my code that read the XML and insert the data to sql server table

```
          XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\TOSHIBA\\Desktop\\student.XML");

       XmlNodeList dataNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/DocumentElement/student");

        foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes)
           {

                   rfidip = node.SelectSingleNode("rfidip").InnerText.ToString();
                   timegetin = (node.SelectSingleNode("timegetin").InnerText);
                   timegetout = node.SelectSingleNode("timegetout").InnerText;

             sql = "insert into tripStudent (Student_ID,trip_number,time_getin,time_getout) values(@rfidip,@trip_number,@timegetin,@timegetout)";
             //sql = "insert into students values(" + rfidip + ",'" + timegetin + "'," + timegetout + ")";
              command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfidip", rfidip);
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trip_number",trip_number);
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timegetin", Convert.ToDateTime(timegetin));
              command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timegetout", Convert.ToDateTime(timegetout));

               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

can any body help me...

Comment: What error are you getting?  Also, if one of the nodes didn't exist in the xml document, then what value do you want inserted into the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectSingleNode return null if the element doesn't exist,
so when you call InnerText on null it throws an exception
so you can change your code like this:

```
rfidip = (node.SelectSingleNode("rfidip") != null)? node.SelectSingleNode("rfidip").InnerText.ToString(): string.Empty;
```

same goes for the rest of your code make sure the element exist

hope this helps you

Comment: yes it works will but when it reach to insert into table it show me the error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Comment: @batoolhamwy what is the value you wish to place if date is missing? two suggestions are 1)setting it to null and allowing null in the database table 2)you can set it to `DateTime.Now()` both cases will give you values acceptable by the database

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with that way, why don't just use `Entity Framework` for updating values, and `XDocument` with xml Parsing?

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""yes""?>
        <DocumentElement>
            <student>
                <rfidip>3000E2009150501900880530DE07</rfidip>
                <timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
                <timegetout>2013-04-09T00:55:59+03:00</timegetout>
            </student>
            <student>
                <rfidip>3000E20075232318015114907CF6</rfidip>
                <timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
                <timegetout>2013-04-09T00:55:59+03:00</timegetout>
            </student>
            <student>
                <rfidip>3000E20075232318015112409741</rfidip>
                <timegetin>2013-04-09T00:53:25+03:00</timegetin>
            </student>
        </DocumentElement>";

//use var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPathGoesHere); if you using xml path
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var studentElements = xDoc.Descendants("student");

studentElements.ToList().ForEach(student => {
    //Create you Insert Query here, see sample below how to get values
    var rfid = student.Element("rfidip").Value;
    var timeIn = student.Element("timegetin").Value;
    var timeOut= string.Empty;
    try {
        timeOut = student.Element("timegetout").Value;
    } catch {
        //since you have no xml value on your time get out, I catch this line
    }
});
```

See refence below:

1.) [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx)

2.) [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

Comment: To expalin this XML is coming from smart Device RFID reader and I need to store this data in My database